# Chrome ignoring hosts file yet seeing it in the `net-internals`

Tags: google-chrome, networking, hosts

I have set up

```
127.0.0.1    example.com
```

in my `hosts` file and it works in every browser except chrome. When checking `chrome://net-internals/#dns` I **do** see that *example.com* is resolved 127.0.0.1, however when waiting long enough I get a

> The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: http://www.example.com/
>
> **Connection to 93.184.216.34 failed.**
>
> The system returned: (110) Connection timed out

error from Chrome that includes the real IP rather than the IP from my hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that when you use a VPN extension in Chrome it will for some incomprehensible reason cause the described inconsistency where Chrome will partially ignore the `hosts` file, but not entirely.